# vscode typescript module import intellisense not working

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am facing this weird problem and I'm trying to fix it.

Say I have a typescript file `foo.ts`.

In this file I start writing a (es6) import statement:

```
import {  } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

If I bring the cursor inside the brackets and I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space-bar</kbd>, I get a dropdown list of suggested classes and types from the module I am important.

This is functionality is broken and I don't know why. Instead I get an irrelevant list of suggestions with all the types in my project:

[image]

I could not find anything useful online. Intellisense in general works. Only the intellisense related to the import statement is broken.

How can I fix that? What could be the cause of this problem?

Visual Code: version 1.12.2
Typescript 2.3.2 (I am using the local typescript, the one installed in my node_modules folder)

Comment: Did you install `@types/react-bootstrap`?

Comment: Yes it is properly installed.

Comment: Does go to definition on the module-specifier work? Also, try disabling the auto import extension.

Comment: I think I understand what is going on. I was trying to import jsx symbols while I was in a .ts file. When I changed the extension to .tsx, the intellisense in the import started working. Thank you very much for your  time.